# How to switch off English International Keyboard in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, language

I have Win10 Home on my laptop in English (United States). Personally I need only two keyboard layouts: English (US) and Russian. But for some reason there appears a third one: English (INTL), which for example uses quotes etc to make symbols outside of standard English alphabet. This keyboard is not listed among those in Settings (I only see Russian and English US there). How do I removed it. Permanently. I never want for it to come back. Please.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following ways:

1. Right-click on your **keyboard** icon, and then left-click on **Settings**.

Select the **Advanced Key Settings** tab, and find the **Change Key Sequence** button. Then, select the **not assigned** option.

Click **OK** to save your settings.

2. You may also change your settings through the **Control Panel** if you cannot locate the keyboard icon.

Head to your **Control Panel** and select **Regional and Language**.

Select the **Keyboards and Languages** tab, and click the button that says **Change Keyboards**.

You will be taken to the **language settings** options described above. Follow the directions to deactivate the foreign keyboards.

Comment: On Windows 10 1909, to get from **Advanced Key Settings** to **Change Key Sequence**, go to the **Advanced Key Settings** under **Windows 10 Settings** > **Device** > **Typing** > Scroll to the bottom. Then click on the **Input language hot keys**. Finally, click on the button, **Change Key Sequence...**. The **Region and Language** menu option in the Control Panel is now **Region**. The **Language** portion has been migrated to the **Windows 10 Settings**.